# Volume problem in Calculus

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid whose base is the region enclosed by $y=x^2$ and $y=1$, and the cross sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis are squares.

Comment: And above? It is bounded by what?

Comment: @Sigur By the tops of the squares forming the cross sections.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw a picture of the planar region described. At height $y$, the cross-section of the solid is a square of side $2x$. Express the cross-sectional area in terms of $y$, and integrate.

Comment: Could you please explain further.  I am still unsure of what the side of the square is.  Are you saying that the side is 2x and therefore the area is 4x^2 and that I would integrate that because that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I assume you have drawn the region, the curve $y=x^2$ is familiar. Note the region is cut off at $y=1$. Draw a line at height $y$, where say $y=1/4$, or anything you like. One side of the square is the distance between the two points where this line meets the parabola. These two points have coordinates $\pm x$, where $x=\sqrt{y}$. The square goes up from the plane of the paper. It has area $(2x)^2$, that is, $4y$. For the volume, integrate $4y$ from $y=0$ to $y=1$.